# Error: Could not find or load main class - When running a JAR at the prompt

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm looking all afternoon how I can run a JAR of a **Spring Boot application** I'm developing.

Generated the JAR through the `mvn clean package` command. The JAR is generated inside the `target` folder, so I run the CMD in this folder and type `java -jar apptest.jar` and then I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class br.com.myapp.Application
```

When I run the application directly on the eclipse, it runs perfectly.

Can you help me?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>br.com.braxxy.adm</groupId>
    <artifactId>brxmind</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>brxmind</name>
    <description>Redmine like Applicaiton for Project Management</description>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>br.com.braxxy.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>           
                        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties> 
                <project.packaging>jar</project.packaging>               
            </properties>            
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>show-profiles</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>            
                </plugins>
             </pluginManagement>
            </build>                              
        </profile>       

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
                <project.packaging>war</project.packaging>
            </properties>   
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                   <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>  
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            </build>                       
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Application.java**

```
package br.com.myapp;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(SystemRoleRepository systemRoleRepository, ProjectRoleRepository projectRoleRepository) {
        return args -> {
            for (ESystemRole role : ESystemRole.values()) {
                SystemRole systemRole = systemRoleRepository.findByRole(role.toString());
                if (systemRole == null) {
                    SystemRole newSystemRole = new SystemRole();
                    newSystemRole.setRole(role.toString());
                    systemRoleRepository.save(newSystemRole);
                }
            }
            
            for (EProjectRole role : EProjectRole.values()) {
                ProjectRole projectRole = projectRoleRepository.findByRole(role.toString());
                if (projectRole == null) {
                    ProjectRole newProjectRole = new ProjectRole();
                    newProjectRole.setRole(role.toString());
                    projectRoleRepository.save(newProjectRole);
                }
            }            
        };
    }
}
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: myapp
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Main-Class: br.com.myapp.Application
```

Comment: Use `build` instead of `pluginManagement`. Also the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` should be used for both the jar and war and you should build 1 artifact regardless of environment.

Comment: Just because I removed the pluginManagement tag already worked!!! I'm just going to adjust this build to at least 1 artfact now. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out that `src/main/Application.java` was an invalid package hierarchy, I changed the hierarchy to `src/main/java/Application.java` and everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

To use the **Spring Boot Maven Plugin**, include the appropriate XML in the plugins section of your `pom.xml`, as shown in the following example:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Build:

```
mvn clean package
```

Run:

```
java -jar target/brxmind.jar
```

Output:

```
...
2021-07-29 07:53:43.557  INFO 18739 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-29 07:53:43.576  INFO 18739 --- [           main] br.com.braxxy.Application                : Started Application in 2.112 seconds (JVM running for 2.476)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes check your pom .xml. If it is showing errors on it in the project explorer file list but when you open the file there is no error. What you can do is to remove all the dependencies and start adding them one by one to find the problematic ones (You can check if the red X sign shows on the pom.xml in the project explorer list). If you locate the problematic dependencies delete the in the .m2/repository directory in your user directory. if it is difficult delete the whole .m2 folder and update all your projects